# GetstreamIO Chat Moderation

Tags: permissions, chat, acl, getstream-io

I'm using Getstream.IO to implement a Livestream type chat.

I see that in the Getstream.IO docs under [Default Permission Policies](https://getstream.io/chat/docs/#channel_permission_policies) a moderator is able to update and delete a message.

When I set a moderator on a channel and login, though, a moderator is only able to update their own messages. I need a moderator to be able to edit and delete another user's message.

I see that in the docs for [Object Ownership](https://getstream.io/chat/docs/#channel_object_ownership) Getstream.IO says, *"If applicable, ownership of the entity is taken into account. This parameter allows you to grant users the ability to edit their own message while denying editing others’ messages. Permission policies are organized as list ordered by priority. A permission policy has the following fields ..."*

How can I list existing permission policies or create a new permission policy using the python API?

At a higher level, using the server side python API or the client side API, is there a way to make it so that Moderator roles do not have the ownership of the entity taken into account?

UPDATE - 
Using `client.get_channel_type("livestream")` I can see that `channel_moderator` has ability to `UpdateMessage` and `DeleteMessage` and `owner` is `False` as I expect: 
[image: picture of debugger for <code>client.get_channel_type("livestream")</code> showing that <code>channel_moderator</code> has ability to <code>UpdateMessage</code> and <code>DeleteMessage</code>]
Unfortunately, that is not the behavior I see when I log in as a user where I have performed `channel.add_moderators([user_id])` for that user, which shows that the changed user has `is_moderator` set to `True`, but the `user` has the `role` of `user`. Do I also need to add a role to the user of `channel_moderator`? Is this documented anywhere?

UPDATE 2: 
I see that in `stream-chat-react`, [`Message.canEditMessage` and `Message.canDeleteMessage` are determined by `this.isMyMessage(message) || this.isAdmin();`](https://github.com/GetStream/stream-chat-react/blob/929cd7ea7c35382e7334fdb1af370276f6e554e3/src/components/Message.js#L124), so it appears that unless one overrides the Message component, the moderators need to be `Admin` in order to edit a message they do not own.

UPDATE 3: 
I can see that in [the tests for `channel_permissions` in `stream-chat-js`](https://github.com/GetStream/stream-chat-js/blob/master/test/channel_permissions.js#L371) that a moderator is indeed supposed to be able to edit and delete a message, just as the permissions matrix in the documentation specifies. I still cannot find a way to get `stream-chat-react` to allow moderators to update or delete a message, however; it's not easy to understand how best to override `Message.canEditMessage`, since `MessageList.render()` automatically constructs using the default `Message` class.

UPDATE 4: 
I was able to get a user added as a `moderator` to be able to edit and delete posts, but only after making that user a global `admin`. I have users that I want to be moderators in a channel but not have the abilities of an admin. I've cross-posted an issue to `stream-chat-react`: [*Allow Moderators to Edit and Delete Messages Without Being Admin*](https://github.com/GetStream/stream-chat-react/issues/36).